# My AJAX file does not work

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I just make a simple AJAX application so that my html page can get some data from the php file through the ajax.js file, I have already put them in the server, so when I access localhost/mypage, it should be executed, however it seems there are some problems therefore things do not happen as my expected way.

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" Content="text/html; Charset=UTF-8">
    <title>
        My Portal
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="images/logo.gif" id="logo" alt="Logo"/>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="images/logo2.png" id="logo2" align="right" alt="google Ltd"/>
        </a>
    </div> 
    <div id="container">
        <div id="function"></div>
        <div id="Display"></div>
        <div id="View"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is the js file:

```
function load(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
            else{ // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }               

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("function").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;         
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

At last is the php file:

```
<?php
     print "<h1>hgfkegfalhgj</h1>";
?>
```

I expect it should print out the above char string in my page, however, nothing can be shown, can anyone tell me where is the problem? I have checked that I have already enabled javascript in my browser, so I am quite sure my html file can call the function in js file.

Comment: it's possible that the status isn't 200. try printing it out

Comment: Not a real answer, but I'd recommend using jQuery. Its code for AJAX requests is much more simple and clean.

Comment: Try changing id of `<div id="function">`.. to some other name. `function` may be causing some issue

Comment: ok, thank you guys, let me try to change it first

Comment: I have tested your codes here: http://www.huinda.com/test/ and it is working fine. Make sure ajax.js, test.php, and your main html file is on the same directory.

Comment: document.getElementById("action").innerHTML=xmlhttp.status; I change function to action and try to add this line before the ready state if statement, however, still nothing can be printed in the html file, I have put all files in the same folder, so should be ok to call the function.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: I have also tested above code and its working great..

Comment: Is your PHP working?
Do you call your html-file via http or via file?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. If you have all those files together in the same directory, it should work. Also use a stand-alone server (like XAMPP/WAMP) when testing locally in your pc.

Comment: I call the file by accessing localhost/Mypage, where all my files are storing in wamp/www/Mypage, and I have tried, when I put the javascript code in the html file but not seperating it, it works fine, so I am confused where is the problem comes from, why the html file cannot call the function when it is seperating in another file

Comment: make sure ajax.js is in the same directory. there is nothing wrong with your code, it should work. Make sure php engine is working. Call your test.php directly (http://localhost/whateverdiryouused/test.php).

Comment: I am very sure they are all in the same directory, that's is why I have no idea why it does not work. Actually, putting all functions in the html file is still okay for me, but I just want to make clear why it does not work, as I work in the same way before.

Comment: You can use a JS debugger and check for JS errors. Check your JS Console for errors/warnings if any. Some use Firebug in FF/Chrome. Use these utilities for debugging.

Comment: When I try to seperate it again, it replys me that load is not defined, so it means the html file cannot find the ajax.js file

Comment: Either it can't find the ajax.js file or the code inside your ajax.js file has errors in it... recheck your code inside ajax.js, or better yet, copy-paste directly, save, and test again.

Comment: oh, ya, you are right, because in my js file, there is another function, when I hide it, I can see the text now, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP but you must set **content** type to `text/plain` . Like :

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Comment: so you mean responseText to response("text/plain")? Actually my original php file is connecting to the databasem but because it does not work, so I try to print some simple line first, but still nothing appear, so if it is not the problem of PHP or Javascript file, it is possible there is some error in the Apache server? If it is the case, can anyone teach me how to correct it, as this is the first time I set up the server by myself, before I just develope website on a pre-built server.

Comment: No , not responseText , it's content(or response) type.

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/plain');

Comment: so you mean I should add this at the beginning of the javascript function?

Comment: You have to add this in your test.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me.

The problem can be any of the following:

1) Check the path to test.php (I would suggest using absolute path in xmlhttp.open() )

2) Your server may not be returning the page correctly (Try opening test.php, and check the output)

You can use browser plugins like firebug, to analyze the ajax request and response, it can give you a better insight.

Answer (score 0):

instead of onLoad function in body tag try with

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
load();
};
function load(){
//your code
}
</script>
```

or try with script load() function before body. I think it will solve your problem.
Also Try to change id, preferably keywords should not be used as id (function id change it to something else)